# Finding list of strings from a list that are present in a file

Tags: bash

I am trying to grep a list of strings inside a file and trying to get the list of strings that are present in the file. Is there a way to get that?

If a, b are in file.txt

```
Eg: grep 'a\|b\|c' file.txt
output : a
         b
```

Comment: Provide a sample of input data your expected output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
list_of_strings=( a b "hello world" )
grep -oF -f <(printf "%s\n" "${list_of_strings[@]}") file.txt
```

That uses a [process substitution](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Process-Substitution) to treat the printed array of strings like a file, then use some grep options (check your man page) to extract the desired strings

Also, using regex alternation like you seem to want:

```
grep -oE "$(IFS='|'; echo "${list_of_strings[*]}")" file
```